# How to insert YouTube video with the Telegram API?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I am using this code, but can't get it to work with the Telegram API. It works fine with an `img` tag, but not with an `iframe. Does anyone have a working example?

```
["tag"=>"iframe",
"attrs"=>["src"=>"*youtube link*"]
];
```

When I test out the created page, `iframe` is missing.

Comment: Do you mean Telegraph?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You cant send video through telegram API.

Comment: Yes sorry, weird was pretty sure I typed Telegraph.  Yes Telegraph
for reference http://telegra.ph/api

Answer (score 0):

```
return [
  'tag' => 'figure',
  'children' => [
        [
            'tag' => 'iframe',
            'attrs' => [
                'src' => '/embed/youtube?url=SHORTURL',
            ]
        ],
        [
            'tag' => 'figcaption',
            'children' => ['Video caption'],
        ]
   ]
];
```